# Node not found error - despite node can be found in console

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I'm trying to insert a piece of HTML at the very top of a document that looks sort of like this:

```
<html>
<frameset onunload="unload()" onload="loadme()" id="topframeset" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" rows="45,19,10,0,*,22">
(...)
</frameset>                                                                                
</html>
```

OK - seems easy. In Firebug I can do:

```
>>> document.getElementById("topframeset")

<frameset id="topframeset" onunload="unload()" onload="loadme()" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" rows="45,19,10,0,*,22">
```

So it finds it fine.

Then:

```
document.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("<h1>hello</h1>"), document.getElementById("topframeset"))

Error: Node was not found
[Break On This Error]   

...ertBefore(document.createTextNode("<h1>hello</h1>"), document.getElementById("to...
```

What's going on?

Comment: Maybe this is because you are trying to build invalid HTML structure. Frameset cannot have `h1` sibling. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.2.1

Comment: I guess that could be. Is it really not possible to have anything but a <frameset> in a document, then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the `<h1>`-textNode in something, eg body

```
document.body.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("<h1>hello</h1>"),
document.getElementById("topframeset"))
```

and it works

Comment: I am sorry but I get the same error trying your code. Node not found. Maybe the HTML structure I am trying to manipulate is broken?

Answer (score 1):

davidkonrad is right, you need to insert the text node in something.

```
var frameSet = document.getElementById('topframeset');
var textNode = document.createTextNode('<h1>hello</h1>');
frameSet.parentNode.insertBefore(textNode, frameSet);
```